# Using a struct inside a struct

Tags: c, struct, nested

How can I use struct A to modify the data inside a struct B. Which has no name, just a type.

```
struct A {
     struct B;
};

struct B {
     int data;
 };
```

Since this is for school, I can't change the code above. I can only use it. I tried something like this for my main but it doesn't work

```
int main (){
      struct A myStruct;
      myStruct.B.data = 3;
      return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry I was just trying to post this as fast as possible that's why I didn't post this with proper c syntax. Anyway, it's my fault for not being clear enough on my question.

I'm aware that my main doesn't work I just want to know if it's ever possible to access the data inside struct B without declaring a name for it inside struct A as I have above. This is the code I was given by a teacher, so I didn't want to modify the structs because I thought maybe she wants us to brainstorm a way to use it the way she wrote it.

The way iharob explains it works perfectly by declaring struct B before struct A, and actually giving a name to struct B.

Is it simply not possible to access that data inside struct B without giving it a name?

Comment: Where did you learn that `main()` definition.

Comment: That struct definition is far from being valid C.  Are you sure that that's all there is to it?

Comment: @iharob Probably K&R, but that doesn't make it's use any more valid.

Comment: @PCLuddite It's terrible, and K&R is quite outdated.

Comment: This would work as a gcc and MSVC extension if `struct B` was defined before `struct A`, but if that is for school I strongly suspect a typo.

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted is not even c code, it would not compile.

Your main mistake is that you don't need to use the `struct` name to access the member. This should be good

```
struct B 
{
    int data;
};

struct A 
{
    struct B member;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct A instance;
    instance.member.data = 3;
    return 0;
}
```

I assume that you posted some sample code, don't do that. Post the actual code that has issues. The code you posted is completely invalid because some one of the definitions lack the type, you can't declare `struct`s without using `struct` in [c](/questions/tagged/c) except if you `typedef` it. So please post the actual code the next time.

And don't build such complicated `struct`s with `struct` members unless you really know what you are doing.